# Самодостаточные Java приложения

Tags: java, развертывание

Я знаю, что некоторые java приложения, например IDEA, носят с собой все необходимое для своей работы, то есть они независимы от наличия jre на компьютере пользователя. У меня возникают два вопроса:

- Как реализовать такое в рамках платформ macOS или Linux?
- Существуют ли какие-либо инструменты, которые могут автоматически вырезать из jre или из jdk, которые я собираюсь поставлять с программой, все элементы, не используемые моей программой? Иными словами, как можно не вручную максимально облегчить используемую jre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте почитать по этой ссылке. Думаю это натолкнет на какие-то мысли.
https://streletzcoder.ru/delaem-java-prilozhenie-nezavisimyim-ot-ustanovki-jre-ili-perenosnyim-portable/

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло. Но хотелось бы узнать ответ и на второй вопрос.